# What URL's do we need to open up for App Center to work for internal apps

Tags: visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

We use a firewall to block internet access for our corporate users.  But we have the ability whitelist important websites that all users have to use.

We distributed an android app with the app center sdk installed.  What endpoint URL's do we whitelist so our users can communicate with App Center including the ability to distribute updates, analytics and crashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the base URLs for App Center endpoints used by the SDK.

- Logs/Crashes from any module: https://in.appcenter.ms
- Distribute:

  - When browser opens the first time you launch the app: https://install.appcenter.ms
  - To check in app updates: https://api.appcenter.ms

Comment: In practice this isn't really working even though we white-listed those URLs.  The biggest factor is that the App Center login page that verifies who you are along with your email address never displays the page's content because apparently the HTML page can't render because it's expecting content from external sources :(

Comment: If you open https://install.appcenter.ms in Chrome and then go to the debugger and look at sources tab you can list additional urls you mention that you would have to whitelist. I guess some of them can be skipped.

Comment: We had to add the whole root domain 'appcenter.ms` then it worked.  One major reason was because we depend on `https://appcenter.ms/login`

Answer (score 1):

Appcenter themselves has published a whitelisting list - https://intercom.help/appcenter/en/articles/1881230-urls-and-ip-addresses-to-whitelist-for-app-center